# Convergence of two Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have 
I have a collection of bounded variation and right-continuous functions, $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and another bounded variation and right-continuous function, $G$, which satisfy
$$\sup_x \lvert F_n(x) - G(x)\rvert \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty$$
In other words, $F_n$ converges to $G$ uniformly on the real line.

What I want to show is
$$\left|\int_{x\in (-M,M)}x^2\,dF_n(x)-\int_{x\in (-M,M)}x^2\,dG(x)\right| \to 0$$

This seems intuitively true but how do I actually show it?

Comment: In this case, you can use Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration-by-parts on both terms (for some reason my previous comment vanished, apologies).

Comment: @user1576713 Thank you. Could you write it out in a bit more detail when you have the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [integration-by-parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration#Integration_by_parts) , for fixed $n$, we obtain
$$ \left| [ F_n(x) \, x^2 ]_{x=-M}^{M}\, - \int_{-M}^{M} F_n(x) d( x^2) - \left( [ G(x) \, x^2 ]_{x=-M}^{M} \int_{-M}^{M} G(x) d( x^2) \right) \right| $$
$$ = \left| [(F_n(x) - G) \, x^2 ]_{x=-M}^{M}\, - \int_{-M}^{M} (F_n(x) - G) \, 2x \, dx\right| $$
Hopefully you can see how to estimate both of these terms by $\sup_x |F_n - G |$.

There are some interesting functional-analytics consequences of this relationship, depending on the origin of the question. (For example, pointwise convergence and norm-boundedness on a compact domain is sufficient to prove the result for all continuous integrands.)